# Do quickblox support show video call in landscape mode?

Tags: android, video, chat, quickblox

I'm trying [Sample-videochat-android](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android) and run ok. But, my app used all in landscape mode, so OpponentView and CameraView still show in portrait mode. Is there config to help?